# Log Sum Exp trick confusion with probability distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian, gaussian

I am struggling to understand how exactly the log-sum-exp trick is applied in mixture models (say Gaussian mixture models) and the EM algorithm.

It is well known that parameter estimation for a mixture:
$$
f(x)= \sum_{i=1}^K \alpha_i \mathcal{N}(\mu_i,\Sigma_i) = \sum_{i=1}^K \alpha_ie^{-(x-\mu_i)^T\,\, \Sigma_i^{-1} \,\, (x-\mu_i)}
$$
can be achieved with the EM algorithm.
The E-step corresponds in estimating in which distribution $i$ a given $x$ comes from. This probability is given by:
$$
p(x\in \mathcal{N(\mu_i,\Sigma_i)}) = \arg\max_i \frac{\alpha_i e^{-(x-\mu_i)^T\,\, \Sigma_i^{-1} \,\, (x-\mu_i)} }{\sum_{j=1}^{K}\alpha_k e^{-(x-\mu_j)^T\,\, \Sigma_j^{-1} \,\, (x-\mu_j)}} \quad (1)
$$
At this point it is common to take the logarithm:
$$
(1) \equiv \arg \max_i \Big\{ \log a_i - \log[(x-\mu_j)^T\,\, \Sigma_j^{-1} \,\, (x-\mu_j)] - 1  + \log \sum_{i=1}^N [(x-\mu_i)^T\,\, \Sigma_j^{-1} \,\, (x-\mu_j)]  \Big\}
$$
where I used the fact that $\log \sum_{i=1}^{N}a_k=1$. **I don't understand how the log sum trick is used now in order to conclude the computation.** My understanding is that arg min will be replaced by min or similar. At this point I cannot figure it out.